# Kullback–Leibler divergence between two gamma distributions

Tags: kullback-leibler, gamma-distribution, exponential-family

Choosing to parameterize the gamma distribution $\Gamma(b,c)$ by the pdf
$g(x;b,c) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(c)}\frac{x^{c-1}}{b^c}e^{-x/b}$
The Kullback-Leibler divergence between $\Gamma(b_q,c_q)$ and $\Gamma(b_p,c_p)$ is given by [1] as

\begin{align}
KL_{Ga}(b_q,c_q;b_p,c_p) &= (c_q-1)\Psi(c_q) - \log b_q - c_q - \log\Gamma(c_q) + \log\Gamma(c_p)\\
&\qquad+ c_p\log b_p - (c_p-1)(\Psi(c_q) + \log b_q) + \frac{b_qc_q}{b_p}
\end{align}

I'm guessing that $\Psi(x):= \Gamma'(x)/\Gamma(x)$ is the *digamma function*.

This is given with no derivation.  I cannot find any reference that does derive this.  Any help?  A good reference would be sufficient.  The difficult part is integrating $\log x$ against a gamma pdf.

[1]  W.D. Penny, *KL-Divergences of Normal, Gamma, Dirichlet, and Wishart densities*, Available at:  www.fil.ion.ucl.ac.uk/~wpenny/publications/densities.ps

Comment: Taking the derivative of the the pdf with respect to $c$ introduces the factor of $log(x)$ you are looking for: that's why digamma shows up.

Comment: If you happen across Pierre Baldi and Laurent Itti (2010) “Of bits and wows: A Bayesian theory of surprise with applications to attention” Neural Networks 23:649-666, you will find Equation 73 gives a KL divergence between two gamma pdfs. Take care, though, it looks like the formula is mis-printed.

Comment: I am looking for a solution to the same problem and find this [one](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/259899864_Computing_the_Kullback-Leibler_Divergence_between_two_Generalized_Gamma_Distributions) is useful.

Answer (score 17):

The KL divergence is a difference of integrals of the form

$$\begin{aligned}
I(a,b,c,d)&=\int_0^{\infty} \log\left(\frac{e^{-x/a}x^{b-1}}{a^b\Gamma(b)}\right) \frac{e^{-x/c}x^{d-1}}{c^d \Gamma(d)}\, \mathrm dx \\
&=-\frac{1}{a}\int_0^\infty \frac{x^d e^{-x/c}}{c^d\Gamma(d)}\, \mathrm dx
    - \log(a^b\Gamma(b))\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x/c}x^{d-1}}{c^d\Gamma(d)}\, \mathrm dx\\
    &\quad+ (b-1)\int_0^\infty \log(x) \frac{e^{-x/c}x^{d-1}}{c^d\Gamma(d)}\, \mathrm dx\\
&=-\frac{cd}{a}
    - \log(a^b\Gamma(b))
    + (b-1)\int_0^\infty \log(x) \frac{e^{-x/c}x^{d-1}}{c^d\Gamma(d)}\,\mathrm dx
\end{aligned}$$

We just have to deal with the right hand integral, which is obtained by observing

$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial}{\partial d}\Gamma(d) =&  \frac{\partial}{\partial d}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x/c}\frac{x^{d-1}}{c^d}\, \mathrm dx\\
=& \frac{\partial}{\partial d} \int_0^\infty e^{-x/c} \frac{(x/c)^{d-1}}{c}\, \mathrm dx\\
=&\int_0^\infty e^{-x/c}\frac{x^{d-1}}{c^d} \log\frac{x}{c} \, \mathrm dx\\
=&\int_0^{\infty}\log(x)e^{-x/c}\frac{x^{d-1}}{c^d}\, \mathrm dx - \log(c)\Gamma(d).
}$$

Whence

$$\frac{b-1}{\Gamma(d)}\int_0^{\infty} \log(x)e^{-x/c}(x/c)^{d-1}\, \mathrm dx = (b-1)\frac{\Gamma'(d)}{\Gamma(d)} + (b-1)\log(c).$$

Plugging into the preceding yields

$$I(a,b,c,d)=\frac{-cd}{a} -\log(a^b\Gamma(b))+(b-1)\frac{\Gamma'(d)}{\Gamma(d)} + (b-1)\log(c).$$

The KL divergence between $\Gamma(c,d)$ and $\Gamma(a,b)$ equals $I(c,d,c,d) - I(a,b,c,d)$, which is straightforward to assemble.

---

#### Implementation Details

Gamma functions grow rapidly, so to avoid overflow don't compute Gamma and take its logarithm: instead use the log-Gamma function that will be found in any statistical computing platform (including Excel, for that matter).

The ratio $\Gamma^\prime(d)/\Gamma(d)$ is the logarithmic derivative of $\Gamma,$ generally called $\psi,$ the *digamma* function.  If it's not available to you, there are relatively simple ways to approximate it, as described in [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Computation_and_approximation).

Here, to illustrate, is a direct `R` implementation of the formula in terms of $I$.  This does not exploit an opportunity to simplify the result algebraically, which would make it a little more efficient (by eliminating a redundant calculation of $\psi$).

```
#
# `b` and `d` are Gamma shape parameters and
# `a` and `c` are scale parameters.
# (All, therefore, must be positive.)
#
KL.gamma <- function(a,b,c,d) {
  i <- function(a,b,c,d)
    - c * d / a - b * log(a) - lgamma(b) + (b-1)*(psigamma(d) + log(c))
  i(c,d,c,d) - i(a,b,c,d)
}
print(KL.gamma(1/114186.3, 202, 1/119237.3, 195), digits=12)
```

Answer (score 16):

The Gamma distribution is in the exponential family because its density can be expressed as:

\begin{align}
\newcommand{\mbx}{\mathbf{x}}
\newcommand{\btheta}{\boldsymbol{\theta}}
f(\mbx \mid \btheta) &= \exp\bigl(\eta(\btheta) \cdot T(\mbx) - g(\btheta) + h(\mbx)\bigr)
\end{align}

Looking at the Gamma density function, its log-normalizer is
$$g(\btheta) = \log(\Gamma(c)) + c\log(b)$$
with natural parameters
$$\btheta = \left[\begin{matrix}c-1\\-\frac1 b\end{matrix}\right]$$

All distributions in the exponential family have KL divergence:

\begin{align}
  KL(q; p) &= g(\btheta_p) - g(\btheta_q) - (\btheta_p-\btheta_q) \cdot \nabla g(\btheta_q).
\end{align}

There's a really nice proof of that in:

Frank Nielsen, École Polytechnique, and Richard Nock, Entropies and cross-entropies of exponential families.

Comment: Didn't know this.  Just a quick question - the $g(.)$ function, does it have to be the same for $\theta_p$ as for $\theta_q$?  So for example, would the above formula be valid for KL divergence of normal pdf from gamma pdf?

Comment: Yes, this formula is for two distributions in the same exponential family.

Comment: @probabilityislogic it's **not** valid for KL(normal||gamma), they have to be in the same distribution, only with different parameters.

Comment: @MaverickMeerkat That's literally what my comment (immediately above yours) says.

Comment: @NeilG your comment is confusing, as you are saying "yes" when the final question of probabilityislogic is does the formula works for normal||gamma. And you use "same exponential family" which is also a bit confusing. I thought it would be beneficial to clear it up some more. I wasn't sure, and I had to go into the "proof" to get a clear view of what's going on.

Comment: @MaverickMeerkat "Yes" was my answer to the first question: "does it have to be the same theta…"  The "gamma distribution" is *one exponential family of distributions* parametrized by two parameters, and so is the "normal distribution".  Two distributions that have different parameters are considered two different distributions—not as you said "the same distribution with different parameters".  I realize that colloquially people sometimes use different (confusing language), but this is how I've seen it in papers and texbooks.